# Signatures in Android

Tags: java, android, draw, paint, signature

I want to make a class which captures a human signature for my Android app. I have this code so far:

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    private static final String TAG = "DrawView";

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    long oldTime = 0;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        // paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path = new Path();

        if (points.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = points.size() - 2; i < points.size(); i++) {
                if (i >= 0) {
                    Point point = points.get(i);

                    if (i == 0) {
                        Point next = points.get(i + 1);
                        point.dx = ((next.x - point.x) / 3);
                        point.dy = ((next.y - point.y) / 3);
                    } else if (i == points.size() - 1) {
                        Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
                        point.dx = ((point.x - prev.x) / 3);
                        point.dy = ((point.y - prev.y) / 3);
                    } else {
                        Point next = points.get(i + 1);
                        Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
                        point.dx = ((next.x - prev.x) / 3);
                        point.dy = ((next.y - prev.y) / 3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        boolean first = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            Point point = points.get(i);
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
            } else {

                Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
                path.cubicTo(prev.x + prev.dx, prev.y + prev.dy, point.x
                        - point.dx, point.y - point.dy, point.x, point.y);

            }
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = event.getX();
            point.y = event.getY();
            points.add(point);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    }

    public boolean checkTime() {
        //Check if there was an input 400 ms ago
        long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diffirence = newTime - oldTime;
        if (oldTime == 0) {
            oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return true;
        } else if (diffirence <= 400) {
            oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Point {
    float x, y;
    float dx, dy;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the line will connect to the latest point when I start drawing again, even when I stop drawing for a while. This is of course not very useful for capturing human signatures, that's why I created the checkTime method. If you stop drawing for 400ms it returns false, when you start drawing again it will start a new line which is not connected to the old line. I only just don't know how I can implement my method, I tried a lot but the line keeps connecting to the latest point, maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Are you using the same `Path`?  I would think you want a new one for each separate segment of the signature.

Comment: Where are you using checkTime()?

Comment: I don't where I have to use checkTime, that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this post](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html) from  [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/), but many thanks to Marc Van Daele!

This is code wich paints the View:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
  private Paint paint = new Paint();
  private Path path = new Path();

  public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
      return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      // nothing to do
      break;
    default:
      return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
  }
}
```

You have to call this activity to start paiting:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably faster to create the path in onTouch and only draw it in onDraw.

Replace onTouch with

```
Path path = new Path();
int prevx=0;
int prevy=0;
int prevdx=0;
int prevdy=0;
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
{
   int x = event.getX();
   int y = event.getY();
   int dx = (x-prevx)/3;
   int dy = (y-prevy)/3;
   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
   {
       path.moveTo(x, y);
   }
   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
   {
       path.cubicTo(prevx + prevdx, prevy + prevdy, x - dx, y - dy, x, y);
   }
   prevx=x;
   prevy=y;
   prevdx=dx;
   prevdy=dy; 
   invalidate();
   return true;
}
```

onDraw will be just

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)  
{
   canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me a little with the code of your solution, I'm not (yet) a very good coder :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately your code doesn't draw a line. I tested the code and the if-else-statement does work, it only won't draw anny line

Comment: please use the debugger to see where it goes wrong (and update the code accordingly). You will need an extra call to canvas.drawPath outside the for loop if the last event is not ACTION_UP (something like if(points.size()>0 && points.get(points.size()-1}.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {canvas.drawPath(path, paint)}

Comment: A straight line is drawed from the left upper corner (coordinates 0,0) to the current location wich I touch. I will use the debugger to search for bugs

Comment: I did something wrong while intilising the floats. It not works, but it is very slow and I am unable to draw a signature. Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it's a typo in your comment and it should read 'it now works', right?  I would suggest to use traceview to see what the performance bottleneck is (see http://tools.android.com/recent/traceviewineclipse) .  Right now,  we are constructing the path every time from scratch in onDraw. It's probably better to create a List<Path> paths and construct the paths (once) in onTouch

Comment: see my edited post which is probably faster. You might need to do some debugging though :-)